# How can I select a calling app from the call action of another app in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I'm currently working on an iOS app ( React Native) that involves making calls. I would like to know if there's a way to select a calling app from the call action of another app in iOS. For example, if I click on a phone number in an email or website, I want to be able to select my app to make the call instead of the default calling app.

I've searched online for solutions, but I haven't found anything that works for me. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here’s an example how android look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNDKx.png)

select a calling app from the call action of another app in iOS

Comment: You will have to add a `URL-scheme` to your React Native App native configurations. Thereafter, you can use the native Linking module to open your app.

`Linking.openURL('your-url-scheme://')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must declare you app capabilities and follow a quite long list of requirements to pass review.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/preparing-your-app-to-be-the-default-browser-or-email-client